# How to put a router inside a router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have created a /admin page that itself has been routed from index.js page. Now I want to access admin/add through the router. However, I am unable to put the router inside the router.

Here is my admin code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const addNewProductRouter = require('./../controller/admin-controllers/add-new-product');
router.use('/add', addNewProductRouter );

router.get('/', function (req,res) {

    if (req.session.userId){
        //Assigns user id to be used in whole admin area
        userId = req.session.userId;

        console.log("Session test from admin " + userId)
        res.render('./../views/admin/admin.pug');

    } else {
        res.send("You need to login first!");
    }
})
```

Here is my add-new-product code

```
const express =require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', (req,res) => {
    console.log("I reached add side");
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Why you don't just add a prefix for the route?

Comment: What prefix should I put? I am sorry I am very new to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have app.js like this

```
...
router.use('/admin', DashboardRouter );
router.use('/admin/product', ProductRouter );
router.use('/admin/another-route', AnotherRouteRouter );
```

If you want to make admin as a prefix for all routes you could do

```
router.use('/', DashboardRouter );
router.use('/product', ProductRouter );
router.use('/another-route', AnotherRouteRouter );
```

then

```
app.use('/admin', router);
```

And your product route file will have all sub routes

```
const express =require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/add', (req,res) => {
    console.log("Add route");
})

router.delete('/delete/:id', (req,res) => {
    console.log("Delete route");
})

module.exports = router;
```

So your routes will look like this:

/admin

/admin/product/add

/admin/product/delete